# Mongo - Count up size of different named nodes (not their values but # of nodes)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

In the json below I would like to find out the counts of all unique / distinct entries under several different nodes.

I think there should be a non-aggregation framework solution but i cant find either aggregation or non-aggregation.

For each node by itself I can count it using:

```
db.collection.distinct('nodaA.title').length
```

And replace the ' ' with the appropriate field for other nodes. But I want to get the counts of 'NodeB.subNoda1.author' and 'NodeB.subNode2.song' and 'NodeB.subNode3.picture' all with 1 query.

I want to get a result something like
title: 1
author: 2
song: 3
picture: 1

```
    "nodaA": [
      {
        "title": "light",
        "id"   : 1
      }
    ],
    "NodeB": {
      "subBnode1": [
        {
          "author": "Gazundheit"
        },
        {
          "author": "Max Weasley"
        }
      ],
      "subBnode2": [
        {
          "song" : "what is love"
        },
       {
          "song" : "gangster's paradise"
        },
       {
          "song" : "wind is gone"
        }
      ],
      "subBnode3": [
        {
          "picture" : "inappropriate"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: With arbitrary depth of named keys it's not really possible with the aggregation framework. If you have a "set depth" ( such as always 2 ) then it's possible but not really practical. The document really should be structured differently, so if you actually explain how you intend to use this information you could get advice on how to do it differently. Otherwise it's pretty much `mapReduce` only on the current structure.

Comment: @NeilLunn oh Doh thanks, i actually forgot about mapReduce completely. I think that's what I'll need to use. I thought if i could get result for 1, i could somehow combine the queries to get results for all at once.

Comment: The main problem here is the "named keys" which are simply not great for database queries. This is why I suggest that you instead "describe your use case" with "real sample data" and how you "really" want to use it. Your "counts" mean "aggregation" of some form or other ( `.distinct()` is an "aggregation" method ) and not something that "queries" actually do. But if you describe you purpose, then you might get useful advice on a better structure. This current one will cause many problems.

Comment: im not sure i have a real use case - my source data i have is from google image search api.

Comment: Okay, so such responses typically have problems and require some "sanitation" ( and some "sanity" ) for typical database usage. Named keys on nodes is reasonable for programatic access from JavaScript ( or lazily converted from XML more often :( )  but pretty impractical for database use. The better option is to "store it how you want to use it" instead of just dumping the feed as returned. Note that 90% of these "API's" ( and google stands out here ) are typically produced by undergraduate interns. So they might be "lacking", to put it mildly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As NeilLunn pointed out it this can only be done with MapReduce, this is what i ended up with:

map:

```
function () {
   emit("titles", this.title);
   for (var key in this.nodeB) {       
        emit(key, this.nodeB[key]);
       }
         }
```

reduce:

```
 function (key, values) {
         var reducedValue = array.length;
         return reducedValue;
|
```

Apologies if this doesnt exactly compile - i modified it from my actual data, but that's the gist of what i did, in case it helps anyone. If more details needed, will add.